# Using JavaScript to delete all cookies for the PayPal shopping cart?

Tags: cookies, paypal, shopping-cart

I am attempting to empty my shopping cart in PayPal. The cookies are heavily encrypted with a session ID as part of the key and therefore is next to impossible to do a simple create cookie with a -1 in the expiration date.

So I tried doing a `document.cookie = "";`  and that does not work – the cookies are still there after I execute the code. So is there a simple "one-liner" to do what I want? I think that all of the domains are set for "PayPal.COM"

Answer (score 0):

You can't set cookies for a domain you don't own.